# the delegate of my delegate is... (design pattern)

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm getting the hang of iOS and working with the different frameworks. My project is getting more complex (of course) and I think I am doing some stuff in a convoluted way.

I'm wondering if there is a simpler design pattern to handle this situation:

**App** with lots of properties held in an array; also holds NSDictionary of NSDictionaries  representing the options for each property.

**Property Editor:** presents table displaying current properties with edit option for detail view

**Detail View:** displays table with all the options for a particular property

I've got this working now by:

**App ->** sets itself as delegate to **Property Editor** which accesses the delegate's (App's) current properties and the arrays of property options

**Property Editor ->** sets itself as delegate for each **Detail view** and sets property on Detail View representing appropriate array of property options from delegate

**Detail View ->**  appropriate array of property options

This seems pretty convoluted. Would it be better to make the **Detail View** delegate my **App**? Is there a design pattern which is clearer? I realize that there is tight coupling between all these classes but I don't see how that is avoidable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not create a singleton class for accessing all your app properties (let's call it `PropertiesContainer`). This class will hold the necessary dictionaries and will be accessed by `[PropertiesContainer sharedInstance]`.

This way all the classes you mentioned don't need to be coupled with each one to access the properties. Now you will have one class which is easily accessed wherever you need it. (and it does not need to know who uses it)

Comment: thanks. I've never used a `sharedInstance` - will have to read up on it. Sound like it would be clearer conceptually + more maintainable than the bizzaro way I have it working now.

Answer (score 1):

Using the MVC pattern, you could create a model object to hold the entire property tree, and use it to communicate the proper subtree with each view or editor.

The Model object need not necessarily be created as a singleton, just have the App create and retain exactly one (or as many as needed).

Comment: But I would be in the same situation where **RootView A** has to pass it (or a ref to itself or set itself as delegate) to **PropertyTableView B** which has to send it (or set itself as delegate) to **PropertyDetailView C** so C can access the list of available options for that particular property. That gets me back into `self.delegate.delegate.dictionaryOfOptions` - unless I misunderstand what you mean.

Comment: If you don't need to filter the properties database outside the model, just make that one Model object the data source delegate for everything.